# Wordpress server response debugging

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, rest, wordpress-rest-api

I have a React (Gatsby) application on a Wordpress backend. Wordpress is using Formidable Forms, and the React app interacts with the Formidable API to create form entries.

Despite making a proper request with the correct API key and formatting (have done a React app on Wordpress backend before), I am getting the following response from the server:

```
code: "jwt_auth_bad_auth_header"
data: {status: 403}
message: "Authorization header malformed."
```

I am trying to modify the response in order to see what header it thinks I am sending.

In my `root/wp-content/plugins/formidable-api/controllers/FrmAPIAppController.php`, there was a promising-looking method

```
private static function process_response( $response ) {
        $body = wp_remote_retrieve_body( $response );
        $processed = array( 'message' => '', 'code' => 'FAIL' );
        if ( is_wp_error( $response ) ) {
            $processed['message'] = $response->get_error_message();
        } elseif ( $body == 'error' || is_wp_error( $body ) ) {
            $processed['message'] = __( 'You had an HTTP connection error', 'formidable-api' );
        } elseif ( isset( $response['response'] ) && isset( $response['response']['code'] ) ) {
            $processed['code'] = $response['response']['code'];
            $processed['message'] = $response['body'];
        }

        return $processed;
    }
```

Modifying the above i.e. changing the `message` key to `message2` did not seem to change the server response.

At the moment, I am unsure how to go about modifying the server's response. It would be amazing to just be able to `console.log` any time I see a variable like `$headers`, but alas, this is neither the browser nor JavaScript.

Comment: I would try to look at `network` tab ot Chrome devtools. You can see client/server communication here, including server responses. If you filter `XHR` and click on the request, you may be able to see details on the right tab.

Comment: @HynekS Hi, thanks for the suggestion. The first snippet of code with the response was from dev tools. I am suspecting the server is modifying my Authorization header when it receives it, and I want to know how the header is being modified.

Comment: Oh, I see. Sorry for that. I would then try to return vars from within corresponding functions and see what is going on here (e. g. return `$response` and temporarily comment out the rest of the function; see the content of `$response` in network tab and so on). Not ideal, but worked for me (using Laravel).

Comment: @HynekS At the moment, I have "fixed" the problem by disabling what I thought was an unrelated plugin (for generating & validating login tokens). I think there was some crossover between plugins receiving requests.